# why git log doesn't show the changes after modifying old comments,?

Tags: git

I need to modify some old comments previously committed.

The way to commit:

```
$git add ***.cpp

$git commit
```

give comments, saved the file, exited out.

```
$git log
```

I saw the comments

After doing this for a few commits, I found I made a mistake, needed to modify the comments for a previous commit(not the last one). Extra JIRA numbers need to be added to the comments,a wrong link needs to be replaced as well.

The I tried:

```
$git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

I modified the comments, saved the file then exited out.

then:

```
$git log
```

I don't see the changes to the comments.

I also tried

```
$git push --set-upstream origin ***
```

I got:  error: failed to push some refs to ....

```
$git log
```

still don't see any changes.

Please kindly advise what I should do.

Comment: *"I modified the comments"* Please add more details how exactly you modified the comments? I hope not in the rebase todo list? *" error: failed to push some refs…"* Also more details required.

Comment: I need to add missing information (JIRA number) and replace a wrong link. sorry for the missing information, please let me know if it is enough. I just started using git from last week for a few times. Thanks.

Comment: No, my question was not about the content of the comment. I asked what commands did you use (ok, `git rebase -i`), what files you edited and what you changed in the files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but when you run `git rebase -i`, you need to change the word "pick" to "reword" for each commit you want to change. When you save and exit, your editor will open once for each commit you asked to "reword", allowing you to re-commit each change with an updated message.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing it out. I changed "pick" to "reword", it works! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Just a note for the future: it's best to avoid writing "thank you" comments. The best way to say thanks is to upvote (or in the case of answers, accept the best one). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment.

(I shouldn't really be writing this comment either, but I figured it's best to let you know. Hope this helps!)